# Unable to scan code39 barcodes - xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing.net

I'm using ZXing.Mobile.Forms to scan the barcodes.
I'm trying to scan the Code39 formatted barcode.
If the barcode has fewer values like 1231214,14123 then it gives me a result. But it is not scanning the barcodes that are having values more than 32digits.
I'm attaching the barcode image which is failed to scan.
[barcode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pu2t.gif)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

This is the code i got from the sample:

```
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
        var option = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { UseCode39ExtendedMode = true, TryHarder = true, PureBarcode = true };
        var result = await scanner.Scan(option);

        if (result != null)
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("It says..", result.Text, "Cancel");
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(true);
```

Thanks,
Ajithbabu

Answer (score 0):

I just made a quick test with iOS device using `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` version `2.4.1` and it is working correctly with your image: `1M8GDM9AXKPO42788`. So it is not a library issue, rather hardware issue, code issue or visibility conditions.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
    var result = await scanner.Scan();

    if (result != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
}
```

Comment: ok i understand, it is working if i have small values in my barcode , also tried to scan the barcode in my CPU, unfortunately it was not working. Please check the question i have included the code now.

Comment: Your question is too broad. `barcode in my CPU` - which barcode type is that? Is it supported by ZXing? Please pay attention to details. I updated my answer with the code that worked for me. What is the hardware(phone model) you are using? Can it be that the camera can't handle very small barcodes? Try another phone. How is the visibility conditions? Can it be that it is to dark? Try to use flashlight in that case.

Comment: Actually my intention is to scan the VIN of cars.

Comment: Yeah, i'm using xiomi redmi 5,  visiblitiy conditions are very clear here. no need of torch or no issues with lights.
i'm not sure whether it can handle small barcodes. But i'm expecting it should handle any size of barcodes which it scans.